# How to create an invoice for one-time payments in Stripe checkout

Tags: stripe-payments

So, I noticed the following behavior. When I create a checkout session with at least on recurring item (subscription), an invoice is automatically created. When the customer opens their Customer Portal, he will see the previous invoices for all subscriptions.

But, when I create a checkout session with no recurring items (one-time payment), invoice is not automatically created. Because of that, when customer opens Customer Portal, he will not see invoices for these orders.

I would like to show all customer invoices in the Customer Portal, both for recurring and one-time payments. So, is there a way generate an invoice for one-time payment and link it to the checkout session?

Comment: No, there is no way to create an invoice for one-time payments. Stripe has a striving community on their discord server, and I would suggest asking these types of questions there. I have received some interesting work-arounds on items I wouldn't have thought of.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just started investigating and testing their API. I contacted their customer support with this question. It appears that there are really no way to create an invoice for one-time payment for the Stripe checkout. It would be a great feature since the behavior of Stipe checkout would be consistent for both recurring and one-time payments, and customer would see invoices for all his orders in Customer Portal. I suggested them to implement it as a future feature. @Brettski

Comment: I made the suggesting 2 years ago. We ended up building our own invoices based on the products sold as the one-time purchase. This is pretty much why they are not doing it, I feel, as you already have the product data you need for an invoice. You will also notice that you don't get reports around products sold across orders as well.

Answer (score 4):

This is now available, but it's a little hidden in the Stripe documentation at the moment, and it's been renamed since the beta checkout invoice feature, which doesn't make it that easy to find. You just need to pass the following for non-reoccurring products...

```
invoice_creation => true
```

...when creating your Checkout Session.

Official Stripe [documentation here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/post-payment-invoices).

Comment: It's now invoice_creation.enabled => true 

Source: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create?lang=python#create_checkout_session-invoice_creation

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Stripe Support for this:

> With regards to the invoices for one time charge, the checkout session
> for one-time payment doesn't generate an invoice. I understand that it
> is helpful for your business to create invoices for a one time charge
> on the checkout session. While there’s currently no way to do that,
> the workaround we can provide for your customer to see their invoices
> on the customer portal, is for you to create the invoice for one time
> charge rather than using the Stripe Checkout.

Comment: You'd think they'd have implemented this feature by now. I can see a lot of demand for it. Makes sense as many businesses need to create one-off invoices in a similar manner as the checkout flow Stripe offers.